# MongoDB $project and index usage

Tags: mongodb

I use aggregation framework to group some data. It was observed that when using $project pipeline stage, it somehow prevents following $match from using the index.
I have an index on field 'timestamp', collection contains 500 000 records.

If I use following command and pipeline:

```
db.collection.runCommand('aggregate', {pipeline: [ { "$match" : { "timestamp" : { "$gt" : 1388425361294 , "$lt" : 1388443361294}}}  ], explain: true})
```

the execution plan is pretty much what is expected, i.e. 4 documents scanned. Excerpt from 'explain':

```
"cursor" : {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor timestamp_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 4,
        "nscannedObjects" : 4,
        "nscanned" : 4,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 4,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "timestamp" : [
                        [
                                1388425361294,
                                1388443361294
                        ]
                ]
        },
        .......
```

But the behavior is drastically changed, once I use any of $project parameters. The following command (the 'country' field may not even exist in any of docs, it doesn't make any difference):

```
db.collection.runCommand('aggregate', {pipeline: [ { "$project" : { "country" : "$country"} ,  { "$match" : { "timestamp" : { "$gt" : 1388425361294 , "$lt" : 1388443361294}}}  ], explain: true})
```

produces this plan:

```
  "cursor" : {
          "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
          "isMultiKey" : false,
          "n" : 500001,
          "nscannedObjects" : 500001,
          "nscanned" : 500001,
          "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 50
          "nscannedAllPlans" : 500001,
          "scanAndOrder" : false,
          "indexOnly" : false,
          "nYields" : 0,
          "nChunkSkips" : 0,
          "millis" : 101,
          "indexBounds" : {

          },
```

....

obviously forces to scan ALL records of the collection, which is unacceptable for me.

Did I miss something important in using of $project pipeline stage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you `$project` first then you are doing a collection scan, outputting ALL documents in that collection with that form. It is the same as saying:

"Give me all documents in the collection with only the `country` field and `_id`"

This result is then passed onto the next pipeline which happens to be a `$match` which causes a full collection scan. You will, of course, have two full collection scans here since the `$match` can no longer use an index either.

You might be able to perform an index scan instead of a collection but as you said the only real way is to actually switch the order of the two around so that you limit your documents and then project.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that current versions of MongoDB automatically optimize the order of projection and match stages when possible.

If a field is used in the match stage and was directly extracted (i.e., projected) from the original document (not added or modified by a previous stage), the aggregation pipeline will automatically be optimized by creating a new match stage with this field as the first stage, thus allowing the use of an index.

Example extracted from the [documentation about projection/match optimization of aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#projection-optimization) :

Aggregation before optimization :

```
{ 
  $addFields: 
  {
    maxTime: { $max: "$times" },
    minTime: { $min: "$times" }
  } 
},
{ 
  $project: 
  {
    _id: 1, name: 1, times: 1, maxTime: 1, minTime: 1,
    avgTime: { $avg: ["$maxTime", "$minTime"] }
  } 
},
{ 
  $match: 
  {
    name: "Joe Schmoe",
    maxTime: { $lt: 20 },
    minTime: { $gt: 5 },
    avgTime: { $gt: 7 }
  } 
}
```

Aggregation after optimization :

```
{ 
  $match: { name: "Joe Schmoe" } 
},
{ 
  $addFields: 
  {
    maxTime: { $max: "$times" },
    minTime: { $min: "$times" }
  } 
},
{ 
  $match: 
  { 
    maxTime: { $lt: 20 }, 
    minTime: { $gt: 5 } 
  } 
},
{ 
  $project: 
  {
    _id: 1, name: 1, times: 1, maxTime: 1, minTime: 1,
    avgTime: { $avg: ["$maxTime", "$minTime"] }
  } 
},
{ 
  $match: 
  { 
    avgTime: { $gt: 7 } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like $project and $match should be used in reverse order in this case.